# Invoking a WCF service using claims based authentication

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services, claims-based-identity, adfs

I have a WCF service deployed in a server machine. We are using claims based authentication to authenticate the WCF service caller. The WCF service is restricted by using IIS Authorization rules.

How do I programmatically invoke the WCF service using .NET? The client app uses a proxy generated using SVCUtil.   calling the service reads the credentials from a configuration file (not the app.config file, in fact the client application does not have a *.config file).

Comment: Could you please answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9632463/claim-based-authentication-using-wcf ?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this blog posting from LeastPrivilege:

http://leastprivilege.com/2010/02/15/securing-wcf-data-services-using-wif/

While the blog goes into specifics of using WIF the only difference should be the token obtained to access the service.